# Web API post request to upload file with data object

Tags: object, asp.net-web-api, attachment

I am working on an API which will accept the file and other details as input object like below

```
attachmentDto:{
Attachment_Description:"Description",
ApplicationId:1212,
etc...
}
```

So I created a method like

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult SaveAttachment(AttachmentDto attachmentDto)
{
var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];
process();
return Ok();
}
```

Does anybody gone through such situation. 
Please provide the solutions or alternatives as well.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is like below:

```
attachmentDto:{
Attachment_Description:"Description",
ApplicationId:1212,
Prop1: prop1value,
prop2: prop2value
}

$.customAjax({
type: "POST",
url: url,
data:attachmentDto,
success: function (returnData) {
                    //success
                },
error:function()
{
//error
}
});
```

Hope this helps you.